# What documentation will I need to apply for a mortgage?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, documents

I'd like to get things in order so the application process can be quick, so I thought I'd scan a bunch of documents beforehand.  What will I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need *all* of these, but if you have them, you should have everything the mortgage people will ever ask for.

1. Recent bank statements from all of your banks (including brokerage accounts)
2. The last two years of W2's
3. A copy of your driver's license
4. A copy of your social security card
5. The last two years of tax returns
6. Your last two paystubs
7. A copy of the signed sales contract
8. A copy of the cancelled check you provided for down payment.
9. If you own more than 25% of a business, the last two years of tax returns for the business

Comment: Excellent list Michael. I was never asked to produce the social security card, but the rest, all were required.